# don't understand bytes integer restriction

Tags: python-3.x, byte

from python3 documentation said that "bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that 0 <= x < 256 (attempts to violate this restriction will trigger ValueError" what is that mean, cause i try :

```
bytes(258)
```

still result bytes object:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

thanks

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects, what you're actually creating with `bytes(258)` is a zero-filled bytearray - it has 258 instances of byte `\x00` in it.

Comment: @bouteillebleu bytes(1) also produce \x00, sorry i still dont understand.....

Comment: `bytes(some number)` makes a bytestring / byte array of `\x00` as long as the number you chose - it uses the number to determine *how long* the bytestring will be, not what's in it.

Comment: @bouteillebleu but why bytes(258) not raising 'ValueError' as documentation explained..

Answer (score 2):

A single byte is indeed "restricted". I'll elaborate in a moment.
What you did, was putting 258 individual bytes of value 0 together.

A byte consists of 8 bits. Imagine each bit like a digit, but intead of decimal, we count in binary, because each digit can only have the value 0 or 1.

So we have a number of 8 digits in binary, so we can count from `00000000 to 11111111`.

If you translate that to decimal, it just so happens to be from `0 to 255`.

Or in hexadecimal from `00 to ff`.

Therefore you cannot have a byte of a value > 255, because otherwise you would need 9 digits on binary to count.
It's not just some arbitrary boundry, it is actually a physical limitation.

---

Edit: To answer your comment.
You can write single bytes like this:

```
bytes([210])
```

or multiple like that:

```
bytes([210, 55, 31, 55, 150])
```

and exceeding the limitations will indeed cause an Value error:

```
bytes([270])
>ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

Note: 256 is not in range(0, 256)

Comment: thanks for the explanation but why python interpreter does'not raise 'ValueError' but instead returning bytes object as documentation said